# Featured video and image thumbnails from external links in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, thumbnails

Is there a way to get a thumbnail from any website link? For example, if I take a link from imgur and post it on my website in the post itself, it shows the image. But when I go to the homepage of my website there is no featured image for that post. Just a great box. How could I generate a featured image of any link I posted from an external website?

I have used the video thumbnail plugin but it only works with certain websites.

Answer (score 0):

try going into page.php of your theme, then search for the_post_thmbnail(). There add the image link

change this line:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

to something like this:

```
<?php $name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ExternalUrl', true);
if( $name ) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
<?php } else {
the_post_thumbnail();
} ?>
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: Could I add this into the child theme page.php?

Comment: Another question. Is there a Wordpress plugin that will generate a thumbnail from any url automatically? Like how Reddit does on their website.

Comment: I can't find the_post_thumbnail in my page.php @akimbo

Comment: I don't see any reason why you cant use it in child page.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a plugin like that but you can write one. If you can't find the thumbnail function you can simply write it in your page.php